# How can I input answers to the Firebase parameterized configuration CLI prompts when I run the command?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to set [the Firebase Parameterized configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=1st#params) in CLI. I want to input the cli prompt answers when I run the commands because I'm using Github actions, and therefore, it is impossible to answer the CLI prompts. How can I solve this issue?

I tried something like this, but it did not work. The cli prompt kept interrupted.

```
$ ENVIRONMENT=prod firebase deploy
```

And this is how my `index.ts` looks like

```js
const environment = defineString("ENVIRONMENT", {
  input: { select: { options: [{ value: "prod" }, { value: "staging" }] } },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to input answers in CLI prompts. You can try using .env files or try to utilize default values. When using parameterized configuration variables, the Firebase CLI first attempts to load the values from local .env files and if they are not present in the .env files it will use the default values. If the default value is not set, it will then prompt for the values during deployment. You’ll have to avoid the scenario where CLI will prompt for answers. Since as you said, there’s no way to answer CLI prompts with Github actions.

Here how you can set a default value.

```
const welcomeMessage = defineString('WELCOME_MESSAGE', {default: 'Hello World',
description: 'The greeting that is returned to the caller of this function'});
```

Here's a sample for .env file

```
PLANET=Earth
AUDIENCE=Humans
```

All these information is available [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=1st#params).